# confidence interval of neural network MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, confidence-interval

I am using DNN for predicting an outcome of a process (with MATLAB NN toolbox). Is there any way to have confidence interval of the outputs?

I asked this question in mathworks website and some one mentioned that Mean Square Error of the outputs that is reported by NN toolbox using "mse" MATLAB function is equal to the variance.

Is that true? I am confused and suspicious to use MSE as variance of NN estimation.

Any help is appreciated.